# Move items between listbox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Sorry if this has been answered before but I searched the site and couldn't find anything that answers my question.

I can move selected items between my listboxes but how do i move all items from one listbox and add them to another one?  if possible I would like to append them to the bottom rather than replacing the items in the other listbox.

The coding i use to move specific items is

```
 Dim selectedItems = (From i In ListBox1.SelectedItems).ToArray()

    For Each selectedItem In selectedItems
        ListBox2.Items.Add(selectedItem)
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(selectedItem)
    Next
```

I cant answer my own question for some reason but many thanks Heinzi, for anyone else having the same problem the following coding should help you.

Dim selectedItems = (From i In ListBox1.Items).ToArray()

```
For Each selectedItem In selectedItems
    ListBox2.Items.Add(selectedItem)
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(selectedItem)
Next
```

Comment: Since you cannot answer your own question, I've moved my comment to an answer so that you can mark it (and, thus, mark this question as answered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same code, but iterate through ListBox1.Items instead of ListBox1.SelectedItems:

```
Dim itemsToMove = ListBox1.Items.ToArray()  ' to make a copy of the list of items

For Each item In itemsToMove
    ListBox2.Items.Add(item)
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to move all items - Worked 100%

```
For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items
            ListBox2.Items.Add(item.ToString)
        Next
```